# TIC TCP Conn Failed [4:0x604000360300]: 1:61 Err(61) <1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1004

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm trying to handle a login with the Facebook SDK but I have this error:

```
2018-08-18 20:50:30.913552+0000 FoodTaskerMobile[1370:39985] TIC TCP Conn Failed [4:0x604000360300]: 1:61 Err(61)
2018-08-18 20:50:30.915921+0000 FoodTaskerMobile[1370:39985] Task <D93AC55D-9E5E-4B25-B48E-5799A19F5F3C>.
<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1004 [1:61])
```

This is my class code:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var bLogout: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var bLogin: UIButton!

    var fbLoginSuccess = false
    var userType: String = USERTYPE_CUTOMER

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil) {
            bLogout.isHidden = false
            FBManagar.getFBUserData(completionHandler: {
                self.bLogin.setTitle("Continue as \(User.currentUser.email!)", for: .normal)
                // self.bLogin.sizeToFit()
            })
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil && fbLoginSuccess == true) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "CustomerView", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

I just fixed a `canOpenUrl` issue (OSStatus error -10814.) and now error 1004 showed up.

Comment: Which is the host? the 1004 is a `URLError.cannotConnectToHost`.

Comment: this is my host http://localhost:8000/restaurant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this error appears in a real device and not in the simulator, this because the mac has a webserver running and so the simulator can resolve it, not the device (it hasn't a webserver on it).

The 1004 is a `URLError.cannotConnectToHost`

Try to use the mac ip instead of the localhost, you can try to use the local network ip if the webserver hasn't a public ip. Check if you can resolve the ip from your iPhone and then it should work.

Comment: let BASE_URL: String = "http://localhost:8000"

let CLIENT_ID: String = ""

let CLIENT_SECRET: String = ""

Comment: Ok, but if you open a browser in your simulator or mac, can you resolve localhost?

Comment: Ok, this is the problem. Check if your webserver is up and configured correctly. You can try to use the local ip too.

Comment: yeah now i understand what you mean, my server localhost was offline on the terminal, now its working and the error disappear 
thank you so much