# http APi request failed to connect error 1004

Tags: swift, xcode, urlsession

I have a problem with my http request from my custom Api using URLSession in Xcode with Swift. This is my code:

```swift
let forecast = self.forecastList[forecastIndex]
let url : URL = URL(string: "https:laundryireland.tk/getForecast?pwd=\(self.CustomApiKey)&temp=\(forecast.temp)&hum=\(forecast.humidity)&pres=\(forecast.pressure)&weat=\(forecast.weather)&wind=\(forecast.windspeed)")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    do {
        let scores = try JSONDecoder().decode(Scores.self, from: data)

            // ...

        } catch {
            print("ops")
        }
    }
task.resume()
```

This code throw an error at the third line already:

```
2019-11-04 12:53:26.701212+0000 DIYP[2554:1119528] [] tcp_input [C6.1:3] flags=[R.] seq=0, ack=2949324956, win=0 state=SYN_SENT rcv_nxt=0, snd_una=2949324955
2019-11-04 12:53:26.702757+0000 DIYP[2554:1119528] Connection 6: received failure notification
2019-11-04 12:53:26.702843+0000 DIYP[2554:1119528] Connection 6: failed to connect 1:61, reason -1
2019-11-04 12:53:26.702897+0000 DIYP[2554:1119528] Connection 6: encountered error(1:61)
2019-11-04 12:53:26.706142+0000 DIYP[2554:1119528] Task <46A61430-630E-48F8-B121-82B1C7BEE5DF>.<2> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1004 [1:61])
```

I saw here: [TIC TCP Conn Failed [4:0x604000360300]: 1:61 Err(61) <1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922498/tic-tcp-conn-failed-40x604000360300-161-err61-1-http-load-failed-error) that the error `1004` is something related to the device not able to resolve the host but this seems odd to me because my URL is on a registered domain running on a remote server which is accessible from everywhere (just type: http://laundryireland.tk in your browser to see that it's working).

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Could it be an SSL certificate issue? I read that Apple supports only `https`, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was first of all a typo: my domain is http://laundryireland.tk while in the code I wrote https://laundryireland.tk .
I found out is still possible to change the app settings to allow `http` connections: right click on `Info.plist`, `Open As > Source Code` then copy paste the following code right after `<dict>` at the top:

```xml
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: This is not a good solution because it "significantly reduces the security of your app". Apple will also require a justification for use of this key when submitting to the App Store. See Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsallowsarbitraryloads).

Comment: Hi @Pigpocket I agree, although this was a school project from 2019 and I rushed to make the API and iOS app in 2 weeks. A better solution would be to get an SSL certificate for the API and use HTTPS instead.